# R Duplicating tibble rows while incrementing one column?

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I'm working with tibbles and fun again, and have run into a problem while attempting to increase the number of days of my data set.

Consider the following tibble:

```
tibble(food = c(rep("sunflower",3), rep("suet",3)), day = c(1:3, c(1,2,5))) 
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  food        day
  <chr>     <dbl>
1 sunflower     1
2 sunflower     2
3 sunflower     3
4 suet          1
5 suet          2
6 suet          5
```

I've decided I want to increase the number of days to 8 for all food types.  This means that there will be 5 new records for sunflower (days 4-8), but only 3 for suet (days 6-8).

```
tibble(food = c(rep("sunflower",3), rep("suet",3)), day = c(1:3, c(1,2,5))) %>% 
    group_by(food) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(freq = ifelse(day == max(day), (8-max(day)+1), 1)) %>% 
    uncount(freq)
# A tibble: 14 × 2
# Groups:   food [2]
   food        day
   <chr>     <dbl>
 1 sunflower     1
 2 sunflower     2
 3 sunflower     3
 4 sunflower     3
 5 sunflower     3
 6 sunflower     3
 7 sunflower     3
 8 sunflower     3
 9 suet          1
10 suet          2
11 suet          5
12 suet          5
13 suet          5
14 suet          5
```

Now I have the correct number of rows, but I need to have day be updated to be 1-8 for sunflower and 1-2,5-8 for suet.  Am I going in the right direction?  If so, what do I need to do before I ungroup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yet another way of doing it (the shortest yet!):

```
df |>
  mutate(day = ifelse(day == max(day), list(max(day):8), day), .by = food) |>
  unnest(day)
```

Answer (score 3):

The go-to function for these kind of operations is `tidyr::complete`. The problem here is that you want a different range of completion for each group, so you should first `split` your data by groups, `apply` `complete` in each group, and unite the data:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tbl |> 
  group_split(food) |> 
  lapply(\(x) complete(x, food, day = max(day):8)) |> 
  bind_rows() |> arrange(food, day)
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 14 × 2
   food        day
   <chr>     <dbl>
 1 suet          1
 2 suet          2
 3 suet          5
 4 suet          6
 5 suet          7
 6 suet          8
 7 sunflower     1
 8 sunflower     2
 9 sunflower     3
10 sunflower     4
11 sunflower     5
12 sunflower     6
13 sunflower     7
14 sunflower     8
```

Comment: upvote for the `complete` function, first time to know this property

Answer (score 1):

I like to use the tidyverse, so someone else will probably suggest a base R solution, but try:

```
tibble(food = c(rep("sunflower",3), rep("suet",3)), day = c(1:3, c(1,2,5))) |>
  dplyr::group_split(food) |>
  lapply(\(x) tidyr::complete(x, food, day = max(day):8)) |>
  dplyr::bind_rows() |>
  dplyr::arrange(food, day)
```

gives

```
# A tibble: 14 × 2
   food        day
   <chr>     <dbl>
 1 suet          1
 2 suet          2
 3 suet          5
 4 suet          6
 5 suet          7
 6 suet          8
 7 sunflower     1
 8 sunflower     2
 9 sunflower     3
10 sunflower     4
11 sunflower     5
12 sunflower     6
13 sunflower     7
14 sunflower     8
```

EDIT:
Having amended to fix my error, I've basically come to exactly the same answer as Maël by a more circuitous route. If the answer if helpful, please accept theirs!

Answer (score 1):

```
tibble(food = c(rep("sunflower",3), rep("suet",3)), day = c(1:3, c(1,2,5))) %>% 
  group_by(food) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(freq = ifelse(day == max(day), (8-max(day)+1), 1)) %>% 
  uncount(freq) %>% 
  mutate(flag = (day==max(day))) %>% 
  group_by(flag,food,day) %>% 
  mutate(day = if(n()==1){day} else {seq(max(day),(max(day)+n()-1))}) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  select(-flag)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 14 × 2
   food        day
   <chr>     <dbl>
 1 sunflower     1
 2 sunflower     2
 3 sunflower     3
 4 sunflower     4
 5 sunflower     5
 6 sunflower     6
 7 sunflower     7
 8 sunflower     8
 9 suet          1
10 suet          2
11 suet          5
12 suet          6
13 suet          7
14 suet          8
```

I used a flag variable to determine which rows had the largest number in day in their corresponding group and then used `seq` to complete the column.